# tikz: How to define a style with 2 boxes in each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to define a style in tikz with 2 squares in each other. However if I use \draw multiple times, it only ever draws the last one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{square} = [draw, rectangle,minimum height=4em, minimum width=4em,
    draw, rectangle,minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em]
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to draw this divisor symbol:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can't nest nodes in Ti*k*Z. There are provision for modifying the "border path", though, but they are quite complex. In this case I would go with a normal node but using a double line for the border.

This in principle should work (you are using a deprecated library and the deprecated `\tikzstyle` command; I changed it. Moreover, never use `pgfplots` without setting a compatibility level; I removed it).

I say in principle because it wreaks havoc with some viewer antialiasing (`evince` is ok, `okular` shows only some of the sides in some zoom...).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta}% arrows is depreacted
\begin{document}
\tikzset{dsquare/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=4,
    minimum width=4em, draw, double, double distance=1mm, line width=0.6pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw node[dsquare] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm just starting with tikz and that really helped